# Dynamic string concat in java

Tags: java, string

I want to contact two string.

Here my code

```
public class StringTest {

 public String concat = "";
 public String txt = "Hello  "+concat;

 protected void print() {
    System.out.println("Output: " + txt);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringTest tb = new StringTest();
    tb.concat = "World";
    tb.print();
  }
}
```

Output: Hello

But I need "Hello World".
It's possible ?

Conditions:
  Should't re-assign variable (get/set , inside method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the execution to be dynamic you need a method.

```
public class StringTest {

 public String concat = "";
 private String txt() { return "Hello  "+concat; }

 protected void print() {
    System.out.println("Output: " + txt());
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringTest tb = new StringTest();
    tb.concat = "World";
    tb.print();
  }
}
```

A field is only calculated when you write an assignment `=` but a method is evaluated each time it is called.

Comment: Should't initialize inside any method( private String txt() { return "Hello  "+concat; })
Should't re-assign variable (get/set , inside method)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the constant String once declared in that way, and that too it is private, you can't access that variable outside.

You almost there but you have to change your Structure and concatination won't work that way.

```
public class StringTest {


 private String txt = "Hello  ";

 protected void print() {
    System.out.println("Output: " + txt);
 }

protected void concat(String toBe) {
    txt = txt + toBe;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringTest tb = new StringTest();
    tb.concat("World");
    tb.print();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value in concat only will be assigned to txt variable when you create a StringText. Instantiate the correct from to concatenate value dynamically and  assign this value inside print method like this

```
public String concat = "";
private String txt = "Hello ";

protected void print() {
   txt = txt.concat(concat);
   System.out.println("Output: " + txt);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   StringTest tb = new StringTest();
   tb.concat = "World";
   tb.print();
 }
```

each call to print method add value contained in concat variable.